# Prove that the matrix is totally unimodular

Tags: matrices, determinant, integer-programming, total-unimodularity

Is there any (theoretic) way I can prove the matrix is totally unimodular? I have tested it by Matlab and know it is TU, however I cannot prove it.

```
-1 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1
 1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
 1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
 0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Yes, But I must prove that any square submatrix of it has a $det\in{-1,0,1}$. You can see the wiki for the definition.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't know that "totally unimodular" allowed for $det = 0 $.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, observe that since $R_1= - R_4$, $R_2= -  R_5$, $R_3 = - R_6 $, then if any sub matrix uses any of these pairs of rows, then the determinant must be 0. Hence, (WLOG) we may assume that rows $1, 2, 3$ are removed (and replaced with rows 4, 5, 6 respectively in the sub matrix determinant calculation). Now call this matrix $A$.

If you look up the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Common_totally_unimodular_matrices), you will see a sufficient condition for Totally Unimodular matrices:

1. Every column of  contains at most two non-zero entries.
2. Every entry in  is 0, +1, or −1
3. If two non-zero entries in a column of $A$ have the same sign, then the row of one is in $B$, and the other in $C$.
4. If two non-zero entries in a column of $A$ have opposite signs, then the rows of both are in $B$, or both in $C$.

Observe that if $B$ is the set of rows 4, 5, 6 and $C$ is the set of rows 7, 8, 9, 10, then this will satisfy the conditions. Hence we are done.

Comment: @remo I came up with it when I started reading about totally unimodular matrices. Off the top of my head, I don't know a proof of the quoted result, though since it's in the appendix of a paper, it should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another, perhaps easier way, of seing this. Your matrix is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \otimes Id \\
Id \otimes \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: The stacking of two totally unimodular matrices on top of each other is not totally unimodular in general. More explanation is required.